# Convolution on x and y axis using fftconvolve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, computer-vision

So I have a matrix with positive integers and I need to convolve it vertically and horizontally with the filter k = [-1, 0, 1].

So what I did to convolve vertically is to make the filter become a matrix with the same dimensions as the matrix containing the positive integers by zero padding and then used fftconvolve from scipy. I did the same thing for the horizontal.

Ex:
matrix = [[3, 3, 3] [4, 4, 4] [5, 5, 5]]

horizontal filter becomes: [[-1, 0, 1] [0, 0, 0] [0, 0, 0]]

vertical filter becomes: [[-1, 0, 0] [0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 0]]

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. I did a couple of tests and I failed most of them.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more logical to have the non-zero part as central as possible? As in `[[0, 0, 0][-1, 0, 1] [0, 0, 0]]` and `[[0, -1, 0][0, 0, 0] [0, 1, 0]]`

Comment: Is using scipy.ndimage.convolve an option? Just passing the matrix and the weights of k.

Comment: @JohanC Yeah that's true, thanks for the advice